# Downloading Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I have downloaded Tensorflow on raspberry pi and when I issue the command `pip3 list` so I can view my `python3` libraries, it is already there. The problem that occurred to me that when I try to use the tensorflow it shows me an error  that it is not found there, I found out that the problem that my tensorflow is downloaded for `python3.5.0` and my Raspberry Pi is using the new python update which is `python3.7.0`

Comment: Can you include the output of `which python` and `which python3`

Answer (score 0):

Currently Tensorflow only supports Python 3.6  It might be an idea to uninstall Python, then re-install from the Python.org website and select version 3.6.  Then, after you install tensorflow using Pip, do:

```
    pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: i tried doing the same as you requested, but it didn't work